# Waiting for only a Part of another Thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I have the following scenario ... there are 2 DJs who are trying to play music, but they can obviously play a CD only if the other DJ is not playing the same CD at that moment so i have those classes and im trying to use synchronize to lock a CD for the other Thread

```
public class cd {
    private boolean played = false;    
    public void play() {
        this.played = true;
        Thread.sleep(2000);       
    }

    //other methods, e.g. skip a song or put the CD back in the collection

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return !(this.played);
    }
}

public class turntable {
    private boolean used = false;   

    public void use() {
        this.played = true;
        Thread.sleep(2000);       
    }

    public boolean isFree() {
        return !(this.used);
    }

    ...

}
```

DJ class:

```
public class DJ implements Runnable {
    CD disk;
    Turntable tt;

    //constructor

    public void run() {

        //do something else, e.g. go to the bar

        tt.use();    
        disk.play();
        disk.skipSong();
        disk.putBack();
        tt.leave();

        //do something else, e.g. smoke a cigarette
    }
}
```

And now I'm trying to block the current CD for the DJ_2 while DJ_1 is in this part:

Part that should block the CD:

```
tt.use();    
disk.play();
disk.skipSong();
disk.putBack();
tt.leave();
```

But the CD should be obviously available, if DJ_1 put it back but is smoking a cigarette now.

So my question is ... how can i block only a part of the run method of a thread and set it in relation to the same part of a different Thread (keep in mind im trying to solve the problem with synchronized)

Comment: I think you should ask yourself, is it the CD that the DJ's cant play at the same time or is it the Turntable that cant be used at the same time. You need to synchronize your turntable not your CD's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the play method in CD class

```
public synchronized void play() {
    while(this.played) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    this.played = true;

    // suppose each DJ can play the disk for 2 seconds and then has to yield the fun to others 
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    this.played = false;
    notifyAll();     
}
```

Then each thread should have the same CD instance

```
public static void main(String){
    CD cd = new CD();

    DJ dj1 = new DJ();
    dj1.disk = cd;
    Thread threadDJ1 = new Thread(dj1);

    DJ dj2 = new DJ();
    dj2.disk = cd;
    Thread threadDJ2 = new Thread(dj2);

    threadDJ1.start();
    threadDJ2.start();
}
```

The Java documentation has good example on this kind of topic [Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: How could i use a notifyAll() instead of the while ? Or is that impossible here?

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` can be on an object not just a method.  In the part that should block use

```
synchronized (tt) {
    tt.use();    
    synchronized (disk) {
        disk.play();
        disk.skipSong();
        disk.putBack();
    }
    tt.leave();
}
```

And everywhere where you `sync` on turntables and disks, sync in the same order, else deadlock, & the music stops :)

Comment: and how do i tell the other DJ that the current one left the tt and put back the CD ? Do i have to put a notifyAll() at the end of each block ?